# Destroy the instance of ViewModel and Page as soon as frame Navigates to another Page

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

Suppose I have 3 pages namely Page1.xaml, Page2.xaml, Page3.xaml.

I have a window and a Frame inside it. Frame's declaration looks like:

```
<Frame Source="{Binding SourcePage}" NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden" />
```

I am doing some work like increasing global counter variable inside constructor and decreasing global counter inside destructor of each page.

Lets name this global counter as x. So the code should look like below:

```
public int x = 0;
```

***Page1.xaml***
(ViewModel associated to Page1 is ViewModel1)

```
public ViewModel1()
{
    x++;
}
~ViewModel1()
{
    x--;
}
```

Similarly:

***Page2.xaml***
(ViewModel associated to Page2 is ViewModel2)

```
public ViewModel2()
{
    x++;
}
~ViewModel2()
{
    x--;
}
```

***Page3.xaml***
(ViewModel associated to Page3 is ViewModel3)

```
public ViewModel3()
{
    x++;
}
~ViewModel3()
{
    x--;
}
```

Now, I change the source of the frame at runtime.

Initially, source of frame is Page1.xaml. So, constructor of the ViewModel1 is called. So value of x becomes 1.

Then I change the source of frame with the help of buttons at runtime to Page2.xaml. So, constructor of the ViewModel2 is called. So, value of x becomes 2. Now, immediately I expect to call the destructor of ViewModel1. So that x should become 1 again. But Destructor of ViewModel1 is never called.

Then again I change the source of frame with the help of buttons at runtime to Page3.xaml. So, constructor of the ViewModel3 is called. So, value of x becomes 3. Now, immediately I expect to call the destructor of ViewModel2. So that x should become 2 again. But Destructor of ViewModel2 is never called.

Then again I change the source of frame with the help of buttons at runtime to Page1.xaml. So, constructor of the ViewModel1 is called. So, value of x becomes 4. Now, immediately I expect to call the destructor of ViewModel3. So that x should become 3 again. But Destructor of ViewModel3 is never called.

When I close the program at that time destructors of these ViewModels are called. I don't want this behavior. I always want to destroy the instance of ViewModel and Page as soon as frame navigates to another page.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

**Update:**

Let me clarify the issue here.

The main point here is I want to get current value of a Property in one ViewModel from another ViewModel.

I have a SessionViewModel as follows:

```
public sealed class SessionViewModel : ViewModelBase, IModule
{
    private static readonly SessionViewModel instance = new SessionViewModel();
    public static SessionViewModel Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return instance;
        }
    }

    private List<IModule> modulesOpen;
    public List<IModule> ModulesOpen
    {
        get
        {
            return modulesOpen;
        }
        set
        {
            modulesOpen = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("ModulesOpen");
        }
    }

    public static IModule GetModuleInstance(string moduleName, string finalName)
    {
        IModule moduleToOpen = null;
        if (Instance.ModulesOpen != null)
        {
            moduleToOpen = Instance.ModulesOpen.SingleOrDefault(mod => mod.ModuleName == moduleName);
        }
        else
        {
            Instance.ModulesOpen = new List<IModule>();
        }
        if (moduleToOpen != null) return moduleToOpen;
        Type module = Type.GetType(finalName);
        moduleToOpen = (IModule)Activator.CreateInstance(module);
        Instance.ModulesOpen.Add(moduleToOpen);
        return moduleToOpen;
    }

    public string ModuleFriendlyName
    {
        get { return "SessionViewModel"; }
    }

    public string ModuleName
    {
        get { return "Session"; }
    }
}
```

Interface I used in above code is IModule whose declaration is as follows:

```
public interface IModule
{
    string ModuleFriendlyName { get; }
    string ModuleName { get; }
}
```

When my Program runs I want to collect the current instances of all the Pages in a List and then I can access the current Instance of any ViewModel from another ViewModel. From that I can get the current value of a Property in another ViewModel. But the instances are not automatically added to the List, so I need to add them to the List in the constructor of the ViewModel and remove them from the List in Destructor of the ViewModel.

Lets see the code for MainWindowViewModel:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : IModule, ViewModelBase
{
    public MainWindowViewModel() //Constructor
    {
        SessionViewModel.Instance.ModulesOpen = new List<IModule>();
        SessionViewModel.Instance.ModulesOpen.Add((IModule)this);
    }

    ~MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        SessionViewModel.Instance.ModulesOpen.Remove((IModule)this);
    }
    ..
    ..
    ..
}
```

In ViewModel1.cs

```
public class ViewModel1 : IModule, ViewModelBase
{
    public ViewModel1()
    {
        SessionViewModel.Instance.ModulesOpen.Add((IModule)this);
    }

    ~ViewModel1()
    {
        SessionViewModel.Instance.ModulesOpen.Remove((IModule)this);
    }
    ......
    ......
    ......
}
```

In ViewModel2.cs

```
public class ViewModel2 : IModule, ViewModelBase
{
    public ViewModel2()
    {
        SessionViewModel.Instance.ModulesOpen.Add((IModule)this);
    }

    ~ViewModel2()
    {
        SessionViewModel.Instance.ModulesOpen.Remove((IModule)this);
    }
    ......
    ......
    ......
}
```

In ViewModel3.cs

```
public class ViewModel3 : IModule, ViewModelBase
{
    public ViewModel3()
    {
        SessionViewModel.Instance.ModulesOpen.Add((IModule)this);
    }

    ~ViewModel3()
    {
        SessionViewModel.Instance.ModulesOpen.Remove((IModule)this);
    }
    ......
    ......
    ......
}
```

Comment: Finalizers run *eventually*, whenever the GC feels like doing a garbage collection; they're a bad fit here. Use IDisposable if you have resources that need to be cleaned up eagerly. Of course, with IDisposable, someone else has to explicitly dispose you, and WPF doesn't have that built-in. If you're willing to use a framework, you might try looking at [Caliburn.Micro](https://github.com/Caliburn-Micro) -- it has interfaces you can implement on your ViewModel to get notified when the page is getting shown/hidden, which sound like they'd do what you're looking for.

Comment: @JoeWhite Please take a look at Update part in my question.

Answer (score 0):

In .Net managed application the memory release is managed by Garbage Collector(GC). GC decides when to call the finalizer according to some complicated rules. So that is the reason it did do what you expected. These articles will be helpful for understanding Garbage Collection in .Net

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0xy59wtx(v=vs.110).aspx
http://joeduffyblog.com/2005/12/27/never-write-a-finalizer-again-well-almost-never/

I am not very sure WHY you need to do that in the finalizer but this article should be helpful for you:

[Dispose Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e(v=vs.110).aspx)

UPDATE:

1. The finalizers will never be called by GC because the view models are added into a static list, unless the whole application is closed.
2. Again, it is wrong to use finalizer to do what you want here. You don't have a control of when it gets called. And in fact when you implement finalizer it actually differs it from being garbage collected. You need to manage the static list yourself.

Comment: The answer to your question in last 2nd line is : please see the Update part in question.

Comment: What can be the solution here? Should I use mediator pattern?

Comment: Can you tell more details about it? Why you want to add them into the static list? When do you want to remove it from the list?

Comment: Ok, so, I want to access a Property from MainWindowViewModel in any other ViewModel and similarly I want to access the value of a property from some ViewModel in MainWindowViewModel. In short, I want to access the value of property contained in one viewmodel in another viewModel.